# Sublime Text 3 - How can i add my PHP tags

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublimetext-snippet

I want to add some custom tags for my development - but I don't know how to do it.

I have tried snippets but it doesn't work because my tags have some special symbols. How can I add my tags so that the snippets work?

Eg: when I fill `z_z` in sublime text, it will auto-fill:

```
print("<pre>".print_r($files,true)."</pre>");
```

When I fill `z_d`, it will auto-fill:

```
echo "<pre>" . preg_replace("/\]\=\>\n(\s+)/m", "] => ", $dump) . "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use sublime snippets, but you just need to escape the `$` sign, as sublime thinks it's a variable, instead of an actual character you want to print out.

To create a snippet, in the top bar go to `Tools > New Snippet`.

You save these snippets as `mysnippet.sublime-snippet` in the `/packages/user folder` (it should save there automatically when you go to save it).

For your **first** one you can use the following snippet, you have to excape the `$` sign by adding `\` infront of it:

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
print("<pre>".print_r(\$files,true)."</pre>");
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>z_z</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

For your **second** one also use a snippet and escape the `$` sign again using a backslash (`\`) again:

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
echo "<pre>" . preg_replace("/\]\=\>\n(\s+)/m", "] => ", \$dump) . "</pre>";
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>z_d</tabTrigger>
</snippet>
```

Comment: Hi, i have a question: z_d on;y can use if have <?php. So how can i use it althought don't have <?php

Comment: Please view a picture. And how i can auto complete <?php, i always to type it - Picture: https://s11.postimg.org/qiwqsxlub/Untitled.png

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't know how to make it

Comment: @PhucVo ok thanks. Now for your question - did you want a new shortcut for when you type <?php> ?

Comment: No i don't have

Comment: @PhucVo If you post another question to stackoverflow and paste the link here, I will try to answer it for you. It is too hard to understand over comments

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `.sublime-completions` file

```
{
    "scope": "helper.sublime.property-name.sass",

    "completions": [

        { "trigger": "z_z", "contents": "print("<pre>".print_r(\$files,true)."</pre>");" }
        etc...
    ]
}
```

Quite useful when you have to do shit load of snippets

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Open Sublime Text 3 and Open **Key Bindings** from **Preferences** Menu

Add below code on right side of **sublime-keymap--user**

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+c"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": { "contents": "echo \"<pre>\"; print_r(${0:\\$variable_to_debug}); die();\n" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Sublime Text 3 and go to Tools > Developer > New Snippet

replace below code `<snippet> <content><![CDATA[
echo '<pre>'; print_r(${1}); echo '</pre>';
die;
]]></content><description>PHP: Pretty print_r</description><scope>source.php</scope>  <tabTrigger>pre</tabTrigger></snippet>`

It's working.